# tcl open pipe seems to misshandle spaces in parameters

Tags: tcl

I have this open:

```
set r [catch {open "|[concat $config(cmd,sh) [list $cmd 2>@1]]" r} fid]
```

where `$config(cmd,sh)` is `cmd /c` and I am trying to pass a file name (and possibly a command such as echo) in $cmd. If there is no space in the file name, i.e. :
cmd is `echo /filename`
 all is well.  With a space, i.e.:
cmd is `echo "/file name"`
 what appears to be passed is:
`\"file name\"`.
When I try this on Linux, I get `"file name"` (no backslashes).  I have tried replacing the spaces in the file name with `"\ "`, but then the target gets two file names, i.e. the space is used to break up the file name.

I am beginning to think I have found a bug in the Windows port of Tcl...

Comment: Do you mean it works fine on *nix systems? I've never figured out how to properly quote command line parameters on Windows.

Comment: The rules for quoting on Windows are arcane, and strictly depend on which C runtime the target application is using. It used to be terrible, but now nearly everyone uses MSVCRT so you can do a half-reasonable job. The Tcl platform binding layer handles most of this for you, and gets it right in most cases: the main exceptions are when calling CMD builtins, as they don't use the normal runtime. (Why? Why?)

Answer (score 3):

Ugh, that looks convoluted!  To pass this sort of thing into the pipe creation code, you need to use exactly the right recipe:

```
set r [catch {open |[list {*}$config(cmd,sh) $cmd 2>@1] r} fid]
```

That is, always use the form with `|[list ...]` when building pipes as the documentation says that is what the pipe opener looks for. (This is the only command like that in Tcl.)
And of course, using the (8.5+) `{*}` syntax is much simpler in this case too, as it is more *obviously* doing the right thing.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the {*} syntax?  Config(cmd,sh) is "cmd /c" which "list" makes into one word, thus trying to execute "cmd /c" instead of "cmd" with a parameter of "/c", unless {*} somehow fixes this.

Comment: OK, the [list {*} build a list that works, but spaces in a parameter still come out with the \" instead of the simple ".  Looks nicer though :)

Comment: Hmm, automating access to CMD.EXE is one of the really tricky topics. The problem is that the CMD.EXE builtins use _different_ quoting rules to virtually every other command on Windows (a legacy of the oddness in COMMAND.COM, which was due in turn to it being written in assembler — with “clever” stuff to try to work out what the user wanted to do — rather than using a consistent C runtime for the parsing). In some cases, writing what you want to a batch file and then running that is the only way to keep sane…

Comment: By the way, is the `$cmd` a single file or a multi-word script? I was assuming the former…

Comment: $cmd is what ever the user types (after a bit of work over).  The simple case is to implement the 'open' equivalent, in which case it is just a file name.  More generally it could be a program name with options and file name(s).  By the way, if I do this:

Comment: `eval exec $cmd` every thing works as expected.  I suspect that the problem is a bug in "open" where it is converting {file name} to "file name".  @Donal I still would like a reference for the {*} syntax.

Comment: I changed $config(cmd,sh) from "cmd /c" to "sh -c". (gygwin is installed) Now 'echo' works.  What is more interesting is that setting $cmd to 'cmd /c "file name" also works. Thanks for looking @Donal

Comment: Tcl's `open` is baroque. It needs a language lawyer to use right. (Hey, we can help there!) Also, the Windows builtin `OPEN` is even worse. It puts the "non" into "non-obvious". :-(